# Support for Google BigQuery JDBC Driver using KNIME

Tags: google-bigquery, jdbc-odbc, simba

I get an error when using the [following JDBC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers/) driver to retrieve BigQuery data in KNIME

The Error Message is in the **Database Connection Table Reader** node as follow:

> Execute failed: " Simba BigQueryJDBCDriver 100033" Error getting job status.

However, this only occurs after consecutively running a couple of similar data flows including the BigQuery driver, in KNIME.

After google searches, no extra info was found. And I already updated the driver / KNIME to the latest version. Als tried to rerun the flow on a different system with no success.

Is there a quota/limits attached to usin g this specific driver?

Hope someone is able to help!

Comment: have you tried asking KNIME support or Simba?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130524807), it seems that you opened it and there's already interaction with the BigQuery's Engineering team. Thus, I suggest following the interaction made there and [subscribing to it](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue) to keep updated as you'll receive e-mails regarding its progress.

Regarding your question about the limits for the driver, the [quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#top_of_page) that you usually have in BigQuery will apply to the Simba driver too (I.e. Concurrent queries limit, execution time limit, maximum response size, etc...).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered a new query limit is set at company's Group level, some miscommunication internally. Sorry for bothering and thans for the feedback!